# why my array is null in second time, when I assigned it's first object to dictionay in objective C, ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

Occured a crazy situation. I assinged values to a mutable array in my first method.it worked properly.this is the my code for it.

```
for  (NSDictionary *final in SectorsArray)
{
    MoreFligh *more = [MoreFligh new];
    more.flightnumber = [final objectForKey:@"FLI_NUM"];
    more.airlinecode = [final objectForKey:@"ARL_COD"];
    more.departureairport = [final objectForKey:@"DepatureAirport"];
    more.departureday = [final objectForKey:@"DepatureDay"];
    more.departuredate = [final objectForKey:@"DepatureDate"];
    more.departuredime = [final objectForKey:@"DepatureTime"];
    more.arrivalairport = [final objectForKey:@"ArrivalAirport"];
    more.arrivalday = [final objectForKey:@"ArrivalDay"];
    more.arrivaldate = [final objectForKey:@"ArrivalDate"];
    more.arrivaltime = [final objectForKey:@"ArrivalTime"];

    [testingArray addObject:more];
}
```

this time testing array is not null and there are two objects with values.no problem.

then in my second method I chencked that array like this.

```
- (void)chk
{
    id bbbbb = testingArray.firstObject;
    NSLog(@"%@",bbbbb);
}
```

then it int the `bbbbb` (I used a breakpoint here) it had two objects with values.then I check with following code.

```
- (void)chk
{
    NSDictionary *bbbbb = testingArray.firstObject;
    NSLog(@"%@",bbbbb);
}
```

at this time it shows testing array has to objects but with no values.
then I have to create a new model class assign value.otherwise after this step it shows only like no value.I have attached some pictures.if anyone wants I can provide any other details.[image: this is when I checked with assinging to dictionary[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWBdY.png)
[[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzYYt.png)

when I create a new model, then it works properly until I checked like above.

Comment: may your model property are the type of weak. Make it Strong. may it will work..!!!

Comment: all those are strong

Comment: It's A simple thing i think you have stored (ID) kind of thing in that than how you can get NSdictionary

Comment: You Can Only Take this objects as MoreFligh

Comment: I didn't get what you said

Comment: Voting to close as "unclear".

Comment: You do need 
testingArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)chk
{
    MoreFligh *bbbbb =(MoreFligh *) testingArray.firstObject;
    NSLog(@"%@",bbbbb);
}
```

Comment: this is not the case.Think I delete this method. then values should be add in to the testing array.but it is also not work.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what the testingArray is, instance variable or temporary variable?

If the instance variable that is, take a look at assignment, make sure no place makes testingArray nil or removeAllObjects.

Or show the .m file completely, let us check.